Showing an inequality using another inequality
Let $ a,b,c,d,e ,k$ be positive  with $k\geq 1$. Define $s_1=k(a+b)$ and $s_2=k(c+d)$. Then is it true that $$[a(s_2-c)+db][(s_2+e)s_1-s_2a]+s_1a[a(s_2-c)+db]-b(s_2+e)s_1d-s_1s_2ab$$ is positive given that
$$-[s_2+e][s_1(s_2-d)]+s_2^2a>0$$
and
$$ad-bc \geq 0$$
I have tried in python for different ranges of the parameters and always found it to be positive. But I cannot prove it. I am guessing there is a clever grouping of terms which I am missing. I understand the computation could be cumbersome but any help will be appreciated. Or anyone could help coming up with a counterexample.

too lazy to do the actual computations, but maybe try looking at your main expression as a function of $k$. Call it $f(k)$. $f$ is a degree $3$ poly in k and it is easy to see that $f(0)=0$. so it would suffice to show that $f'(k)\geq 0$ for $k\geq 0$, which would be a degree $2$ poly in $k$. maybe the discriminant of that will have something to do with what you can infer from the $2$ inequalities you are given.

Let $m := k-1 \ge 0$.
We need to prove that
$f(a, b, c, d, e, m) > 0$
given that $g(a, b, c, d, e, m) > 0$
and $ad - bc \ge 0$ and $a, b, c, d, e > 0$
and $m \ge 0$.
We have
\begin{align*}
 &g(a, b, c, d, e, m)\\
 ={}& (m+1)^2(c+d)\Big[ad - bc - (c+d)(a+b)m\Big] - (m+1)(cm+dm+c)(a+b)e.
\end{align*}
Thus, $g(a, b, c, d, e, m) > 0$ implies
$ad - bc - (c+d)(a+b)m > 0$ i.e.
$$m < \frac{ad - bc}{(a + b)(c + d)} =: m_0. \tag{1}$$
We have
$$f(a, b, c, d, e, m) = a(1+m)(cm+dm+d)(a+b)e + a(1+m)\cdot h(a, b, c, d, m)\tag{2}
$$
where
\begin{align*}
 &h(a, b, c, d, m)\\ 
 :={}& (c+d)^2(a+b)m^2 + (c+d)(a^2+ad-b^2+bc+2bd)m + (a+b)(ad-bc)\\
 \ge{}& (c+d)(a^2+ad-b^2+bc+2bd)m + (a+b)(ad-bc).\tag{3}
\end{align*}
From (2) and (3), it suffice to prove that
$$(c+d)(a^2+ad-b^2+bc+2bd)m + (a+b)(ad-bc) \ge 0. \tag{4}$$
If $a^2+ad-b^2+bc+2bd \ge 0$, clearly (4) is true.
If $a^2+ad-b^2+bc+2bd < 0$, using (1), we have
\begin{align*}
 &(c+d)(a^2+ad-b^2+bc+2bd)m + (a+b)(ad-bc)\\
 \ge{}& (c+d)(a^2+ad-b^2+bc+2bd)m_0 + (a+b)(ad-bc)\\
 ={}& \frac{(ad-bc)(2a^2 + 2ab + ad + bc + 2bd}{a+b} \\
 \ge{}& 0.
\end{align*}
We are done.

Thanks a lot! How did you come up with the grouping in (2)?

@stochs After collecting the polynomial in $e$, I found that $f = f_1 + f_2 e$ and $g = g_1 - g_2 e$ where $f_2 > 0, g_2 > 0$. So we discard $e$ to prove that $f_1 \ge 0$ given that $g_1 \ge 0$.
